# Field Calculator Sum Across Other Layer

Tags: qgis

I'm hoping to reach into another layer and sum the relevant fields with Field Calculator, but am having some trouble.
I have the layers "Countries", and "Settlements". I want to create a new field in Countries called Population, which is the sum of all the matching Settlements. That is, the sum of all Settlements where Settlements->Owner_Name matches Countries->Name. Any advice on how to go about this? I haven't found a lot of detailed tutorials about reaching across layers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) Have a look at the `aggregate` function, 2) provide more details, 3) better post questions about QGIS here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field to the Countries layer, named Population with this expression:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='Settlements',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:="id",
    filter:="Owner_Name"=attribute(@parent, 'Name')
```

This should work.